# Pivot Table calculated field

Tags: excel, pivot-table

[Pivottable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZyE1.png)

As you can see in my picture linked above i'm trying to add a field on my pivot table that shows what % the 7 result is of the 28 Result.

I know i have to add a calculated field but i don't understand how to create the formula that links to specific columns in the pivot table

Answer (score 1):

Calculated Fields can only do calculations based on the totals of other Fields.

As you want to do analysis based on different items within a field, you actually need to add a Calculated Item within the Column Label field.

Click on the 7 or 28 in your PivotTable to select the Field in which you want to create the Calculated Item. From PivotTable Tools > Options > Fields, Items & Sets, you can now choose Calculated Item...

Select the field that was used in Column Labels and then perform the calculation on the items in that field. Select the 7 item in the list, click Insert Item, type the divide symbol, then select the 28 item in the list and click Insert Item again. Specify a name for the new Item and Click OK.

[image: Img]

You'll now have the new Calculated Item in that Field.

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm having the following issue when trying to select item, Is it because I'm calculating the Average 7 & 27 ?

"averages standard deviation and variance are not supported when pivottable report was calculated items"

Comment: Yeah you can't have a Calculated Item for a Field and also try to take the Average. You'll either need to perform some calculations outside the PivotTable or create two PivotTables - you may still run into issues with two PivotTables if they're sharing the same data cache. Hiding the Calculated Field in the table with Averages may work. If not, you would need to look for how to create a new PivotTable cache for the same data.